# How to manually set a dynamic default field value in Django forms?

Tags: django-models, django-forms

I am trying to create a form where the default date field value should be changed from time to time.
I have created a model with the two field values. I intend to change these fields from time to time for thousand of pages. If i can do this in the admin panel once for all the pages then i get a little stress off.

- {default_start_date and default_end_date}

i would like to have these fields called as the page loads to be the default values for two other fields

- {start_date and end_date}

My question i dont know how i can do this? Django or Java Script? or Both?

Answer (score 0):

You could do this using a django model and its corresponding admin interface:

```
class DateRange(models.Model):
    start_date = models.DateField()
    end_date = models.DateField()

admin.site.register(Author)
```

This would let you adjust the `DateField` in the admin. It also lets you call the current value of `DateRange.objects.all()[0].start_date` wherever you need that in your app/templates.